# Как сделать список объектов имея список значений свойств C#

Tags: c#, рефлексия

У меня есть следующий список: `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>`.

Каждый элемент представляет следующее:

```
Key - это название свойства (задается атрибутом)
Value - это список значений для этого свойства
```

Соответственно сам вопрос, как мне сделать N количество объектов со свойствами Value?

Вот код, который я сейчас использую. Он работает частично, значение свойств он устанавливает, но я не знаю как это сделать столько раз, сколько у меня значений свойств.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Parse<T>(IList<string> lines) where T : new()
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(
        x => Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(CsvPropertyAttribute))).ToArray();

    //Тут 2 элемента Key, в котором Values около 2к элементов
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> propertyValuesPairs = FormatFile(lines); 

    var obj = new T();

    foreach (var item in propertyValuesPairs)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = props.FirstOrDefault(
            x => x.GetCustomAttribute<CsvPropertyAttribute>().CsvName == item.Key);

        property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(item.Value[0], property.PropertyType), null);
    }

    //вернется объект у которого Property1 = item.Value[0], Property2 = item.Value[0]...
    return obj; 
}
```

Comment: `propertyValuesPairs.Select(x => x.Value)`? Или сделать foreach в foreach

Comment: @Frehzy нет, через 2 цикла это не сделать. Тут проблема в другом совсем, у меня коллекция `ИмяСвойства - КоллекцияЗначений`, т.е 1 свойство - много значений, и таких свойств >2

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = from item in propertyValuesPairs
            from value in item.Value
            select new {item.Key, value};
```

Тестил следующим образом (использовал лист вместо IEnumerable. Разницы в данном случае не будет):

```
//заполнение листа
List<string> oneList = new()
{ 
    "10",
    "9",
    "8",
    "7",
    "6"
};
List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> propertyValuesPairs = new();
propertyValuesPairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>("1", oneList.Take(2).ToList()));
propertyValuesPairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>("2", oneList.Skip(2).Take(3).ToList()));

var items = from item in propertyValuesPairs
            from value in item.Value
            select new {item.Key, value};
foreach (var item in items)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(@"Key: {0}. Value: {1}", item.Key, item.value));
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось всё проще. Количество элементов в Values всегда будет одинаково для всех свойств в моём случае. Соответственно можно вынести всё внутрь цикла, который будет исполняться столько раз, сколько значений для свойств:
Таким образом, если у меня будет 1000 значений для свойств, то будет сделано 1000 объектов с указанными свойствами (в `propertyValuesPairs`)

```
int count = propertyValuesPairs.First().Value.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var obj = new T();

    foreach (var item in propertyValuesPairs)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = props.FirstOrDefault(
                x => x.GetCustomAttribute<CsvPropertyAttribute>().CsvName == item.Key);

        if (property == null)
            continue;
        property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(item.Value[i], property.PropertyType), null);
    }
    yield return obj;
}
```

Comment: Но это всё равно 2 вложенных цикла. Я предлагаю реализацию через один цикл. Насколько это будет быстрее - неизвестно, нужно тестить.  Сама функция внутри foreach остаётся практически такой же, но цикл всего один

Comment: @Frehzy оно одинаково быстро будет работать (вероятнее всего). Первый цикл - количество значений для свойств, второй - цикл по самим свойствам. Так что если в вашем коде сделать установку значений для свойств через рефлексию - без еще одного цикла вы не обойдетесь никак

Comment: Я так и не понял, почему нельзя обойтись без ещё одного цикла. Что может помешать этому? Ну, задача решена, поэтому ладно, проехали

Comment: @Frehzy потому что у меня N значений и ограниченное количество свойств. Объектов должно быть столько же, сколько значений возможных

Comment: Так `from item in propertyValuesPairs  from value in item.Value select new {item.Key, value};` как раз таки этим и занимается. Количество элементов будет = количеству свойств*количество значений. Как раз то, что вам и нужно